# What is the significance of packages in java?

Tags: java, package

I really don't understand as i've just learnt java and haven't experimented with packages so much so i've this ave question that why is packages signigicant ?

Comment: Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Comment: To make types easier to find and use, to avoid naming conflicts, and to control access, programmers bundle groups of related types into packages.

Comment: thank you Arvind Kumar Avinash